# How to properly encapsulate inside a React component?

Tags: reactjs

There is a component

```
return (
<div className={classNames}>
  <img
    className={[classes["user__avatar"]]}
    alt={props.altAvatar}
    src={props.srcAvatar}
  />
  <h1 className={[classes["user__name"]]}>{props.userName}</h1>
  <Button className={[classes["user__logout"]]} onClick={logOut}>
    Logout
  </Button>
</div>
```

I initialize it in another component with such data

```
<UserProfile
        className={[classesAppContainer["app__body"]]}
        userName={userProfileName}
        alt={userProfileName}
        src={userProfilePhoto}
      />
```

The question is, how do I transfer Alt and Src data not from the outside, but encapsulated?